# Make Flex List Vertical Not Horizontal

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I work with CSS and I don't have a lot of flex-box experience as I've only recently began adopting it as the web continues to drive forward. I am working with code that I don't quite understand. The DIVs are all floating next to each other in a horizontal grid but I want each `.styled-container` to be vertical with each `.styled-container` in it's own row. I'm not sure which CSS lines are causing it to do this so I'd like to

1) Understand the flex better and what's causing it

2) How to make this list vertical

I appreciate it!

**CodePen**
https://codepen.io/CoderPerson87/pen/zYGBpPE

**HTML**

```
<div class="family-container">
  <div class="styled-container">
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQMAAADCCAMAAAB6zFdcAAAAYFBMVEUAZq7///8AY60AXKozfLnC0eTD1+kAX6t8ps49e7iOr9MAUKUqeLe50OVqlMNGg7zu9foAWakAV6iEqtDM3OtxncnW4+9IiL+xxt+80uaQs9SYuNeevdqyyuE4f7rI2+sR6XqnAAACJUlEQVR4nO3c21aCQBSAYQYM8lSOGallvv9b1lQayAzsWWYsNv93PRez/+UBREgSAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADGJU2KLKjvzf2P7CWb3YVsRxHB7jfznQnarPve4O3Zmcnny3CDEUSwe9PRwBxt35u8LZegq4HJVUewr0bQQHWE7wTdDUyu9tvhJ4GggdoI9u00YHcDs1P5djgnEDVQGeE3gayBwgjr3wTCBmap7GCpmkDaQFmE9bY6m7SBqgj1BPIGiiLYQ30yeQNzUPLBeJkgpoGSCI0EUQ1URGgmiGugIELhGTef5xENzDLte4jrpFPPULldTIIWDe99D3Elf4MsDVo8NE2H/UIINAiuL5486/fFP+7470U3uPesn9GABjSgAQ1oQAMa0IAGNKABDRwa0MChAQ0cGtDAoQENnNE0OI6rQZI8Nk3Cl1hUNkg9V8/CF9omOhv4hgrLPMvLvme4WvYckWDlaVCmw77c6MRE8DTQkCAqQrNBWWhIEBOh0aDMdCSIiHDZQE8CeYSLBuXg/4pUJYxQb6ArQZJY0XFCrcFGWQJhhGqDjcJbWSQRKg00JviM4Pu/VahBy7nloHVHODfQek+XIMKpgd4E3RF+Gmi+x7MzwncD3Qm6Inw1yNXcvBLSGsE10J+gPcIqezqOIIGLEHwSyCF9H/hvh1JtT4TRc64MAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIDMBzHnJaGfdaRoAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" />
  <p>Company Name</p>
  </div>
  <div class="styled-container">
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
  <p>Company Name</p>
  </div>
  <div class="styled-container">
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
  <p>Company Name</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.family-container{
  margin-bottom:96px;
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.styled-container{
  flex-direction:column;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  margin-right:32px;
}

img{
  max-width:64px;
  grid-column:span;
  border-radius:120px;
}
```

Comment: flex-direction: column;

Comment: Use flex-direction: column in "family-container" div

Check: https://codepen.io/CoderPerson87/pen/zYGBpPE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flex-direction: row;` in class `.family-container` for each `.styled-container` set in horizontal, for vertical use `flex-direction: column;`

```
 .family-container{
  margin-bottom:96px;
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.styled-container{
  flex-direction:column;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  margin-right:32px;
}
img{
  max-width:64px;
  grid-column:span;
  border-radius:120px;
}
```

for reference:- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/